# Converting 64 bit raster to 16 bit

Tags: qgis, tiles, raster-conversion, bit-depth

I have drone captured aerial image that I'd like to add as a layer to a project on GIS Cloud. The file is currently 64 bit which is not supported on GIS Cloud. Using QGIS I ran Raster-Conversion-Translate. I've ran the tool multiple times choosing different output bit depths and compression limits. I keep getting errors citing non-standard tile sizes.

If anyone has any ideas can you let me know?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 64 bit can mean many things, what exact datatypes are your band(s)?

Comment: The error message is "nonstandard tile width 21698, convert file" and "nonstandard tile length 11607, convert file"

Comment: The starting file is a 659 MB .tif file. It's a series of drone captured images stitched together and georeferenced. I wasn't involved in the collection of the images or the processing to create the .tif file.